# UPnP in visual basic: Does is still work?

Tags: vb.net, com, interop, upnp

tl;dr - I'm attempting to open internal and external port 4305 to my local address at 192.168.1.103 through UPnP with Visual Basic code.

I've been searching for the better part of 20 hours looking for a way to open these ports on my router through UPnP code for VB. So far, nothing has enabled me to trigger a port through VB. To keep a long story short, I've attempted about 4.3 different options with varying success. These are:

Microsoft's Interop/COM NATUPnP Library (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ics/network-address-translation-traversal-interfaces)

NetworkLight_VB (An old program I hoped I could use for reference, http://www.thijsschreijer.nl/blog/?p=450)

ManagedUPnP Library (This is the .3, I spent little time exploring this lib as it's C#, but still think it's worth mentioning, https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=managedupnp)

UPnPc/MiniUPnPc (http://miniupnp.free.fr/)

Portmapper (https://github.com/kaklakariada/portmapper)

**NATUPnP 1.0 Type Library**

Having a little prior knowledge with Interop services through excel based programs, this seemed like a pretty good solution, however it didn't get very far as the COM object `NATUPNPLib.IStaticPortMappingCollection` would always return as nothing. I imagine this would be due to `NATUPNPLib.UPnPNAT` also returning empty, despite Visual Studio showing it as an initialised COM object. With little info or guidance other than "Your UPnP is probably off" (It wasn't) I decided to see if there was another way, and moved on.

**NetworkLight_VB**

In an attempt to look for working examples of UPnP triggering through VB I quickly realised that this isn't a very hot topic and has barely been talked about in years, with this program being no exception. Opening the program it seemed to run fine, though I had no indication of it actually working as intended, with my router showing no UPnP activity on the port it was trying to hit. I believe there's still potential here with the library being used, but I'm not sure how to utilise it properly or reference it within my own program.

**ManagedUPnP Library**

This is the same as with the UPnP library used by the NetworkLight_VB program; not sure how to use it. (Being entirely self taught, my knowledge foundations are shaky at best. The only references I've used successfully are through Visual Studios 'add reference' option like with the NATUPnP Interop service)

**UPnPc/MiniUPnPc**

This showed a lot of promise as a potential workaround, allowing the use of a stealth CMD window to do the dirty work, but this also failed. The worst part is that I have no idea why. Running it seemed to work without issue, and it echoed a success in triggering UPnP, however my router told me otherwise. Checking the UPnP list showed no open port, and any attempt to communicate between my host and client programs failed.

By this point I was ready to just give up and port forward manually. Surely, if everything I was trying kept failing then there must be something wrong with my setup, computer, something that was misbehaving. But I gave it one more shot.

**Portmapper**

This nifty little java program worked like a charm. I entered the info, checked my router wizard and, lo and behold, there was the port sitting open and ready. Testing my client and host programs, I confirmed that it was working exactly the way I wanted it to. There was just one problem: getting it into my program. Browsing the author's website I found that it did in fact have a command line interface with examples, though my pitiful (and very tired) attempts to use that CLI didn't work. This shouldn't be too hard to work out though.

What does bother me however is that it needs Java installed on the computer to run, and since this is a peer-to-peer based program, replacing 'asking a user to port forward' with 'asking a user to install Java' is undesirable (Though, if all else fails, then so be it. Pressing install is far easier than navigating a router gateway wizard).

Ideally I would like to have the NATUPnP Interop service or any of the libraries work so that I'm not running code outside of the main program, but I really want this to work so anything that does is probably what I'll use.

Any guides on how to use the libraries, examples of working programs or suggestions on alternative methods is very much appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, I can feel you're pain.  But maybe the problem is more your implementation rather than the tool you're using.  Are you able to show us how you implemented your solution using the preferred library then maybe we might be able to help